# "Thumbs-up/thumbs-down" vs "give the finger"

Tags: phrases

Why is the noun *thumb* in "give the thumbs-up or thumbs-down" always in the plural and the noun *finger* in "give the finger" always in the singular?

Comment: Right, you can extend two middle fingers.

Comment: Because "thumbs up" and "thumbs down" were the signs made by the audience/mob in the Roman amphitheater when judging the fate of a gladiator.  It was a vote, not the indication of a single person.

Comment: That's because the thumb gestures are a group thing, and giving the finger is a way to express a single individual's thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

**Thumbs Signal** - thumbs-up or thumbs-down, usually in the plural, despite the fact that we use only one thumb when we perform the action.

> - **description** - It's a common hand gesture achieved by a closed fist held with the thumb extended upward or downward in approval or disapproval, respectively. These gestures have become metaphors in English: "The audience gave the movie the thumbs-up" means that the audience approved of the movie, regardless of whether the gesture was actually made. [**Wikepedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbs_signal)
> - **origin** - Few gestures can have a stranger history than the familiar 'thumbs up'. Everyone agrees that it hails from the days of gladiatorial combat in ancient Rome, when a decision had to be made concerning the fate of a beaten warrior. Peter Quennell, in his book on The Colosseum describes what has now become the generally accepted scenario: In the sovereign's presence. thc crowd advised their ruler. **Waving cloths and displaying up-turned thumbs, they shouted 'Mitte!' (Let him go free); or, by turning down their thumbs, they vociferated 'lugula!' -- recommending that the fallen man should pay the penalty.** When the emperor happened to share their feelings, he confirmed the crowd's verdict ... and ... with polico verso, downturned thumb, ordered his immediate execution.

**meanings** - Not every "thumbs-up signalling" means approval, though. A study carried out throughout Western Europe, on what interpretation people give it, showed the following results

> - O. K.    738
> - One  40
> - Sexual insult    36
> - Hitch-hike   30
> - Directional  14
> - others   24
> - not used     318 
>     (Based on 1,200 informants at 40 locations)
>
> [**Gestures: Their Origin and Meanings**](http://bernd.wechner.info/Hitchhiking/Thumb/)

No matter whether or not it was first used in Rome, as Hot Licks has mentioned, it was used as a vote by the crowd. And that must be why we use it in the plural till this day. Then again, "give someone the finger" is obvious: it's singular because it's only one finger.

Comment: In  Britain, of course, it's 'flick two fingers'.